# Is it possible to send delete/put requests to a Azure AD secured api or get jwt Token as String using aadHttpClientFactory

Tags: javascript, typescript, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, httpclientfactory

I have a custom Api which I secured with Azure AD like the following tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient
Thats working great.

now I have the following Code to make a GET request to my custom API (working):

```
 this.context.aadHttpClientFactory
.getClient('MY_API_URL')
.then((client: AadHttpClient) => {
  console.log(AadHttpClient.configurations.v1); 

  return client
    .get(
      `MY_API_URL/SOME_ROUTE`,
      AadHttpClient.configurations.v1
    );
})
.then(response => {
  var res=  response.json();
  return res;
}).then( (res: any[]) => {
...

HERE I WOULD LIKE TO GET MY TOKEN

});
```

So this is working how I expect it to work.
But the aadHttpClientFactory only supports GET and POST requests

Now my Idea was to just make some PUT/DELETE requests with jQuery and use the Bearer token I got above (tested with postman and its working).
But then I realised, that I won't get the token that easy.
When I console.log(AadHttpClient.configurations.v1) I only get this:
[image]

Sure I could just change my API to use POST instead of PUT/DELETE but that would be pretty ugly
Does anyone has an Idea on how I could get the token as a String to do custom requests with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now.
Maybe my answer will help someone later.
according to philippe Signoret's answer the is the fetch() function.
I had to use it like following:

```
        this.context.aadHttpClientFactory
        .getClient(api_url)
        .then((client: AadHttpClient) => {
          return client
            .fetch(
              MY_URL,
              AadHttpClient.configurations.v1,
              {
                method: METHOD, //put/DELETE etc.
                headers: [
                  ["Content-Type", "application/json"]
                ],

                body: JSON.stringify({
                  YOUR REQUEST BODY
                })
              }
            )
          });
```

Answer (score 2):

[AadHttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-http/aadhttpclient) supports the [`fetch(url, configuration, options)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/sp-http/aadhttpclient?view=sp-typescript-latest#fetch-url--configuration--options-) method, where `options` can include all of the request configuration options supported by the [Fetch API](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#requestinit).

So, to make a DELETE request, you would do something along the lines of:

```
client
    .get(
      `MY_API_URL/SOME_ROUTE`,
      AadHttpClient.configurations.v1,
      {
          method: 'DELETE'
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
import { AadHttpClient, HttpClientResponse, IHttpClientOptions } from '@microsoft/sp-http';

.... /** code removed for brevity **/.....

const options: IHttpClientOptions = {
   method: 'DELETE',
};

await this.context.aadHttpClientFactory.getClient(this._applicationId).then((client: AadHttpClient) =>{
                return client.fetch(requestUrl, AadHttpClient.configurations.v1, options)
                .then((response: HttpClientResponse) =>{
                    if(response.status === 204){
                        deleteResult = true;
                    }else{
                        deleteResult = false;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
```

Your application id may look like: api://some_guid
Your requestUrl may look like: https://yourapi/api/controller/id

Hope this helps someone!